# Correct way to find models by their association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Both of these produce the same result:

```
User.where(account: 1)
User.where(account_id: 1)
```

But the generated SQL is different:

```
/* User.where(account: 1) */
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = 1

/* User.where(account_id: 1) */
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = $1  [["account_id", 1]]
```

Also both of these generate the same SQL as the first version:

```
a = Account.find(1)
User.where(account: a)
User.where(account_id: a)
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = 1
```

So which is the correct way to find a model by its association? Is the second version safer than the first? I tried to search for what's happening at the SQL level in the second version but I coudn't find anything.

Comment: There isn't a "correct" way, to answer your question. Ruby as a language allows doing even a simple thing in various ways. See this either as a positive or a negative aspect, depending on your problem. So, in your case, you may opt for whatever approach suits you best; there are no major performance differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference in your case. But if the `account` association is polymorphic, e.g. when there is a Business account and a Personal account, then the `where(account: a)` will generate something like `WHERE account_type = 'Business' AND account_id = '123'`, while `where(account_id: a)` will generate just the `WHERE account_id = '123'`.

Comment: Do you know the term for this style of SQL `account_id = $1 [[account_id, 1]]`?

Comment: This is not SQL actually (if you try to run it in any SQL editor – it will fail with a syntax error), this is just a log message, it can look whatever the database connection adapter developers like. The difference in logging between the two queries in your question is because I believe two different form of parameter substitution are used, e.g. `User.connection.select_all "select * from users where account_id = :account_id", account_id: 1` and `User.connection.select_all "select * from users where account_id = ?", 1`. Those two queries will generate identical SQL, but be logged differently.